# Sql query needed for selecting the count from a table

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following fields.

```
Col A  Col B
-----  -----
I1      10
I1      10
I2      16
I3      14
I2      16
```

I need a query that should give output as follows:

```
ColA   Col B  Count
----   -----  -----
I1      10      2
I2      16      2
I3      14      1
```

How to write a query for this.
Please help

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY` the two columns and use a `COUNT` to get the number of identical rows..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about doing the questioner's job for him.

Answer (score 3):

```
select colA, colB, count(colB) as `Count`
from your_table
group by colA, colB
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5c1b/1

Answer (score 1):

If `ColB` is always the same for a specific value of `ColA`, you can use `max`:

```
select  ColA
,       max(ColB)
,       count(*)
from    YourTable
group by
        ColA
```

Otherwise, you'd have to explain how the `ColB` value in your result is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, Count(ColB) FROM T GROUP BY ColA, ColB
```

Answer (score 1):

use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  colA, colB, COUNT(colB) as Total
   FROM tableName
   GROUP BY colA, colB
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know

```
select [Col A] ,[Col B] ,count(*) [Count]
    from <table>
    group by [Col A] ,[Col B]
    order by [Col A]
```

Comment: I tried. But its not working. the count is not calculated correctly.

Comment: @raji: This is as per the example you have provided. Please tell me how the Col B values. Is it 10 always for I1 ? or can it have some other values also?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, COUNT(1) AS Count
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ColA, ColB
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ColA, colB, COUNT(colB) AS Count
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ColA,ColB 
ORDER BY ColA,ColB
```

See [this SQL fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3f3c/1)