# Query for count

Tags: sql, db2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sql query needed for selecting the count from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407723/sql-query-needed-for-selecting-the-count-from-a-table)

I have a table with the following fields.

```
Col A  Col B
-----  -----
 V1      I1
 V1      I1
 V1      I2
 V1      I3
 V2      I1
 V2      I2
 V2      I2
```

I need a DB2 query that should give output as follows:

```
ColA   Col B  Count
----   -----  -----
 V1      I1     2
 V1      I2     1
 V1      I3     1
 V2      I1     1
 V2      I2     2
```

How to write a query for this.
Please help